# How can I steal someone else's Bitcoins?

Tags: hacker-experience

The game has some fake Bitcoins in it and every player has a Bitcoin address, just like his bank account. And just like their bank account, there must be a way to steal their Bitcoins, but how can I do that?

Is it possible to steal someone's Bitcoins and how?

Comment: Another one of those dubious question titles. Happens a lot with this game.

Comment: And a big hello to our friends at the NSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stealing Bitcoins requires you to acquire their public address and their private key. There's only one way to do this: camp their logs.

A log entry containing your private key is generated whenever you

1. Log into your bitcoin account. The login is persistent, so you won't need to log in that often.
2. Collect from a bitcoin miner.

It's difficult to acquire them except by luck. However, one particularly cunning way is the following:

1. Find a player IP. Use this IP as a trap: edit a fake bitcoin address and key into this player's logs.
2. Expose this player's IP in the logs of a public server.
3. Camp your trap player's log. As soon as somebody (*the victim*) logs in, immediately sign log into that IP.
4. The victim will have to sign out of their own wallet to try signing into the fake one. After finding it doesn't work, they'll likely log back into their own wallet.
5. Camp your victim's log. As soon as they log back into their wallet, an entry containing their key will be generated.

Once you have their address and key, you can just log into their account on the bitcoin market, then transfer them to your own wallet. Bitcoin transfers are anonymous; there are no associated log entries.

In order to protect your bitcoin key, make sure you always queue up a log clear before collecting or logging into your account.

Note that currently, bitcoin addresses/keys cannot be changed, so once you have someone's key, you can siphon their account indefinitely. (Well, until the round resets.)